# Curvature zero - a basic question came up from a theorem

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I encountered this theorem some time ago.

[image: pic1]

I think I was able to prove it pretty easily.
But it made me thinking about the following.

For some curve and for its parametrization, could we have that at some fixed point $s = s_0$ the curvature $\kappa(s_0) = 0$ but there is no neighborhood $U$ around $s_0$ in which $\kappa(s)= 0$ in the whole neighborhood $U$?!

What is the answer to this question?
And what is the justification of it?

Comment: Sure: if a curve has an inflection point at $s_0$ then it only need have curvature 0 at $s_0$. Presumably by analogy to $x^4$ a curve could reach sufficient flatness to also do this without $s_0$ being an inflection point; if it is only as flat as necessary it will also have curvature 0 at just one point.

Comment: @Soundwave I am not sure I follow. Could you elaborate? You mean this specifically about curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and more specifically about graphs of functions?

Comment: Any curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ having an inflection point can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$ and be an example, but you could also "twist" such a curve around its inflection point and get a curve that has no embedding in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but meets this. If you keep twisting towards a half-turn you'll get curves where you might not think of as having an inflection point per se anymore because the curve curves in broadly the same direction, but it still has a point of instantaneous 0 curvature.

Comment: But $x^4$ does not even have an inflection point at $x=0$, right? It has an undulation point there, no? Maybe you meant $x^3$?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was confusing. "Curve with an inflection point" and $x^4$ are different examples.